# How does LightGBM calculate the leaf values for the first tree in regression?

Tags: python, regression, lightgbm, boosting

When plotting the first tree from a regression using `create_tree_digraph`, the leaf values make
no sense to me. For example:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
X, y = load_boston(return_X_y=True)

import lightgbm as lgb
data = lgb.Dataset(X, label=y)

bst = lgb.train({}, data, num_boost_round=1)
lgb.create_tree_digraph(bst)
```

Gives the following tree:

[image: tree]

Focusing on leaf 3, for example, it seems like these are the fitted values:

```py
bst.predict(X, num_iteration=0)[X[:,5]>7.437]
```

```
array([24.78919238, 24.78919238, 24.78919238, 24.78919238, 24.78919238,
       24.78919238, 24.78919238, 24.78919238, 24.78919238, 24.78919238,
       24.78919238, 24.78919238, 24.78919238, 24.78919238, 24.78919238,
       24.78919238, 24.78919238, 24.78919238, 24.78919238, 24.78919238,
       24.78919238, 24.78919238, 24.78919238, 24.78919238, 24.78919238,
       24.78919238, 24.78919238, 24.78919238, 24.78919238, 24.78919238])
```

But these seem like terrible predictions compared to the obvious and trivial method of taking the mean:

```py
y[X[:,5]>7.437]
```

```
array([38.7, 43.8, 50. , 50. , 50. , 50. , 39.8, 50. , 50. , 42.3, 48.5,
       50. , 44.8, 50. , 37.6, 46.7, 41.7, 48.3, 42.8, 44. , 50. , 43.1,
       48.8, 50. , 43.5, 35.2, 45.4, 46. , 50. , 21.9])
```

```py
y[X[:,5]>7.437].mean()
```

```
45.09666666666667
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LightGBM's leaf node output values show the prediction from that leaf node, which includes multiplying by the learning rate.

The default learning rate is `0.1` (https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html#learning_rate). If you change it to `1.0`, you should see that the the output value for leaf 3 is `45.097` (exactly the mean of `y` for all observations that fall into that leaf node).

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
X, y = load_boston(return_X_y=True)

import lightgbm as lgb
data = lgb.Dataset(X, label=y)

bst = lgb.train({"learning_rate": 1.0}, data, num_boost_round=1)
lgb.create_tree_digraph(bst)
```

[image]

Similarly, if you set the `learning_rate` to something very very very small, you should see that most of the leaf nodes from the first tree will have values very similar to the global mean of `y`. The global mean of `y` (`y.mean()`) in your example data is `22.532`.

```py
bst = lgb.train({"learning_rate": 0.0000000000001}, data, num_boost_round=1)
lgb.create_tree_digraph(bst)
```

[image]

I don't recommend setting `learning_rate=1.0` in practice, as it can lead to worse accuracy. For gradient boosting libraries like LightGBM, it's preferred to use a learning rate `< 1.0` and higher `num_boost_round` (try `100`) , so that each individual tree only has a limited impact on the final prediction.

If you do that, you'll find that each subsequent tree added to the model should add a small incremental improvement in accuracy. This is what happened in your original example. The global mean of `y` (`y.mean()`) in your example data is `22.532`. For a group of records with local mean `45.097` and with learning rate set to `0.1`, the first tree predicted `24.789`. Not a great prediction by itself, but a better prediction for that group than the global mean.